# Compactness of the solutions of an initial value problem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that for any $y_0 \in [a,b]$, 
The initial value problem:

$dy/dx = f(x,y) $,
$y(x_0) = y_0$

has a unique solution $y=\phi(x;y_0)$ on the interval $I = [x_0 - d, x_0 +d]$ (for some d)

I would like to show that the solutions depends on the parameter $y_0$ continuously.

To show that I would like to show that the set $\{\phi(x;y_0): y_0 \in[a,b]\}$ is a compact set in $C^\infty(I)$, the set of continuous functions equipped with supremum norm.

How can one show that?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is bounded then everything follows directly from Arzela-Ascoli. Here you get uniform boundedness and equicontinuity from the fact that the derivatives are uniformly bounded and the fact that $y_0$ is being drawn from a bounded set.

If $f$ is not bounded then there is more to be done. I think ultimately you need to find a single interval $[c,d]$ such that for any $y_0 \in [a,b]$ you have $\phi(x;y_0)$ bounded for $x \in [c,d]$. Each $\phi$ of course has such an interval, but the problem is to find a single one for all of the $y_0$.